# How to make a Jenkins Testng suite fail badly to trigger Post Build , email notification

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, webdriver, testng

I have the following Testng program scheduled on a Jenkins server.

It checks for one of two strings, if neither are found, It means an API has failed an i want it to alert me.

But the test fails,it doesn't fail badly enough for Jenkins to generate the email to alert me, in the post build.

It does a finance check based on a postcode and address, and if string "Great news!" or "Thank you" if neither are found it to fail so the post build will send out an alert.

Any Pointers greatly appreciated.

```
package Finance_check;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Check_Finance_Latest {

    static WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void check_finance() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // linux
        // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
        // "//usr//lib//chromium-browser//chromedriver");
        // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
        // "/home/user.name/Selenium/chromedriver");
        // driver = new ChromeDriver();

        // Windows
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\Chrome Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        driver.get("https://www.somesite.com/");

        // driver.manage().window().maximize();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("CarShop | UK car supermarket | used cars for sale"));

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Accept Cookies')]")).click();

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/apply-for-finance')]")).click();

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Continue')]")).click();

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        Select title = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@name,'title')]")));
        title.selectByVisibleText("Dr");

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        WebElement fname = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'firstname')]"));
        fname.sendKeys("Agent");

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        WebElement lname = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'surname')]"));
        lname.sendKeys("Smith");

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        Select day = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@name,'dateOfBirth_day')]")));
        day.selectByVisibleText("6");

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        Select month = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@name,'dateOfBirth_month')]")));
        month.selectByVisibleText("January");

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        Select year = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@name,'dateOfBirth_year')]")));
        year.selectByVisibleText("1972");

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        WebElement phone = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@type,'tel')]"));
        phone.sendKeys("0207 485769");

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'emailAddress')]"));
        email.sendKeys("ITTestingDonotContact@example.com");

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        System.out.println("Filled in name / age details");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Continue')]")).click();

        WebElement pcode = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'postCode')]"));
        pcode.sendKeys("W1A 2HG");

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Find Address')]")).click();

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        Select address = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@ng-model,'addressKey')]")));

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        address.selectByVisibleText("7 The Road, LONDON");

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Complete Pre-Application')]")).click();

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        try {
            String high = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4[contains(.,'Great news!')]")).getText();
            System.out.println("high string found");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        try {
            String low = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4[contains(.,'Thank you.')]")).getText();
            System.out.println("low string found");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        String credit_rating = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4")).getText();
        System.out.println("Credit Rating Result = " + credit_rating);

        if ("Great news!".equals(credit_rating)) {

            System.out.println("High Credit Found");

        } else if ("Thank you".equals(credit_rating)) {

            System.out.println("Low Credit Found");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Neither String found");

            try {
                throw new Exception("wheres my fiance message ? - fail!");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

                driver.quit();
            }
        }
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use TestNG Assert (http://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.11/index.html?org/testng/Assert.html) for your test.

Instead of `throw new Exception("wheres my fiance message ? - fail!");`
you can use `fail("wheres my fiance message ? - fail!")`.

This will tell TestNG your test has failed properly.